# Restaurants with hechsher for locusts

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, product-recommendation, bugs, restaurant

Are there any restaurants in Israel (or other) that have a hechsher endorsing the preparation and eating of locusts in their restaurants?

Comment: http://www.the-eucalyptus.com/restaurant/ has [served it](http://www.haaretz.com/blogs/routine-emergencies/when-god-gives-you-locusts-make-locust-stew.premium-1.507666), but I can't find out what they did Kosher-wise, and they don't advertise their certification.

Comment: Wow!  12 bucks for soup of the day!  ...can't imagine how much they get for the locusts!

Comment: You might want to contact the "zoo rebbe" (Slifkin, I think is his last name?) Apparently, since he's cooked it, himself, he may know of places (besides him) that do it. Friendly advice - after you eat these locusts, don't "jump" to conclusions so quickly :-)

Comment: Please note that I completely revamped my answer after corresponding with the people mentioned in it.

Comment: You can purchase locusts from Slifkin's website here: https://www.biblicalnaturalhistory.org/product-page/locusts

Answer (score 4):

I wrote to [Dr. Ari Greenspan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1600/ari-greenspan) and [R' Dr. Ari Zivotofky](http://torahinmotionusa.org/users/dr-ari-zivotofsky), who have hosted "[Mesora Dinners](http://halachicadventures.com/the-mesora-dinner/)," serving foods with interesting Halachic statuses, in various places. As far as they know, there are no kosher restaurants that include locusts on their menus.

When they held the Mesora Dinners in the United States, the menu *did not* include actual locusts; they just got a shout-out in the form of "chocolate locusts." When they held it in Jerusalem, in [The Eucalyptus](http://www.the-eucalyptus.com/), which is [certified by the Jerusalem Rabbinate](http://www.eluna.com/rest/Eucalyptus.asp?mumu=708), they did serve locusts, which Dr. Greenspan and R' Dr. Zivotofsky provided. R' Dr. Zivotofky said that he thinks Eucalyptus "still sometimes serves them when there is a specific request."

Comment: If I recall correctly R' Ovadiah Yosef z'l said that even if your custom is not to eat them, they don't treif up your dishes, and there was a restaurant that was therefore exploring the option -- is that Eucalyptus?